# Why is $ids not visible inside callback of whereHas()?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, orm, lumen

I have the following code:

```
$ids = $adGroupsOfUser->pluck('id');
$permittedTables = extensiontables_registry::whereHas('ad_groups', function($q){
  $q->whereIn("ad_group_id", $ids);
})->pluck('extensiontable_name')->toArray();
```

I get this error:

```
local.ERROR: ErrorException: Undefined variable: ids in E:\aether-backend\app\Http\Helpers\modelInteractions.php:51
```

Why is `$ids` not visble in the callback of whereHas()? What can I do to "get it inside"?

Answer (score 1):

Pass the variables from parent scope using `use(...vars)`

```php
$ids = $adGroupsOfUser->pluck('id');
$permittedTables = extensiontables_registry::whereHas('ad_groups', function($q) use($ids) {
  $q->whereIn("ad_group_id", $ids);
})->pluck('extensiontable_name')
  ->toArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, I found it out myself and wanted to post right now, but you  were quicker than me! :D